# Laravel Homestead/Vagrant box stuck on box: Calculating and comparing box checksum

Tags: laravel, vagrant

I'm in the process of setting up an existing Laravel project and can't get past adding the homestead box.

The instruction is: `vagrant box add laravel/homestead`

It goes through a 5-10 minute of process then fails at `box: Calculating and comparing box checksum...`

I'm on Linux Mint 18.3 and have tried these instructions with the latest virtualbox(6.0.14) and multiple versions of vagrant 2.2.2, 2.2.4, and 2.2.6(latest).

I get different errors for 2.2.6 vs other versions. For 2.2.6 I get 
`/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.6/gems/vagrant-2.2.6/lib/vagrant/util/file_checksum.rb:65:in 'load_digest': uninitialized constant FileChecksum::Errors (NameError)`

For other versions I get a red warning that states: 
`The specified checksum type is not supported by Vagrant: .
Vagrant supports the following checksum types:
md5, sha1, sha256`

I'm not too experienced with Vagrant and am not sure how to approach this issue. There also isn't too much information about this particular problem, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the Homestead directory, enter:

```
git fetch --all --tags --prune`
//then enter: 
git checkout tags/v9.4.1 (check github for the latest stable version)
```

Vagrant box adds laravel/homestead should work. Or at least that just worked for me when I was having a similar issue.

Comment: Upgraded back to vagrant 2.2.6 and checked out the 9.4.1 branch and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: I am also having this issue, can you clarify what directory I should be in to run these commands please?

Comment: Shaun, you would run all of this in the Homestead directory. If you followed the Laravel docs, it would be ~/Homestead.

Answer (score 1):

Try to download previous version of the box, ex.

```
vagrant box add --box-version 8.2.1 laravel/homestead
```